# How to pass input parameter in an angular5 directive

Tags: angular5, angular-directive

I'm trying to pass an input parameter to a directive, but it's seems that the component doesn't pass it. Here the code:

app.component.html

```
<div appTest [test]="bbbb">AAAAA</div>
```

test.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef,Renderer,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appTest]'
})

export class TestDirective {

    @Input() test: String;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { 
        if (this.test == "bbbb")
            renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement,'backgroundColor','red');
    }

}
```

When I run the code with ngserve, the background-color isn't red, but if I comment the if clause, the background color is red.

In the chrome developers tool I found out that this.test is undefined...

What is his problem??

Thank you in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your test value in quotes or Angular will search for a variable named `bbbb`:

```
<div appTest [test]="'bbbb'">AAAAA</div>
```

Or you can put a variable directly without quotes.

Then, in your directive, you have to implement `OnInit` and put your code of your constructor in it:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

public ngOnInit()
{
   console.log(this.test); // will print 'bbbb'
   if (this.test == "bbbb")
     renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement,'backgroundColor','red');
}
```

When you're using `test` in the constructor, the variable is not yet
instantiated.